# Sort multidimensional array from high to low in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

25Hi I have checked on here and cant find a similar result so if this has been asked I do apologies.

Anyway, I am generating an multi array which has been generated by a nice little class.

Anyway the array comes like this when output:

```
array(2047) {
    [0]=> array(6) {
        ["name"]=> string(4) "name"
        ["gamesplayed"] => string(2) "26"
        ["points"] => string(2) "26"
    }
    [1]=> array(6) {
        ["name"]=> string(4) "name"
        ["gamesplayed"] => string(2) "26"
        ["points"] => string(2) "42"
    }
    [2]=> array(6) {
        ["name"]=> string(4) "name"
        ["gamesplayed"] => string(2) "26"
        ["points"] => string(2) "16"
    }
    // and so on
}
```

My question is... Is there an easy php function or a neat way on sorting the array into high to low using the points value?

I have had a look at a few php functions but they are just for standard arrays with a single value.

Thanks for any help given :)

**UPDATE**

I have tried this and it does not sort by points.

Here is the class I am doing it with:

```
//create sort value
private function sorting_table($a, $b){
    return $a['points'] - $b['points'];
}

//sort all users into a table and order the highest to the lowest
public function output_prediction_table($pdo, $year){

    //get all uers and put in an array with games played and points.
    $getallusers = $pdo->prepare("SELECT userid FROM userpredictions WHERE year=:year");
    $getallusers->execute(array(':year' => $year));

    //create the multidimentional array
    $multidimentional_array = array();

    while($fetchallusers = $getallusers->fetch()){

        $multidimentional_array[] = array(
            'name' => $this->get_username($pdo, $fetchallusers['userid']),
            'games' => $this->get_games_played($pdo, $year),
            'points' => $this->make_points($pdo, $year, $fetchallusers['userid']),
            'userid' => $fetchallusers['userid']
        );

    }

    usort($multidimentional_array, array($this, 'sorting_table'));

    $output = '<table class="table-striped">';
    $output .= '<tr class="t-h"><td class="t-c">Position</td><td>Username</td><td>Games Played</td><td>Points</td></tr>';
    $tablenumber = 1;

    foreach($multidimentional_array as $newarray){

        $output .= '<tr><td class="t-c">'.$tablenumber.'</td><td><a href="/user/'.$this->sluggify($newarray["name"]).'/'.$newarray["userid"].'/" title="View '.ucwords($newarray["name"]).' Profile">'.ucwords($newarray["name"]).'</a></td><td>'.$newarray["games"].'</td><td>'.$newarray["points"].'</td></tr>';
        $tablenumber++;

    }

    $output .= '</table>';

    return $output;

}
```

I am not getting any errors, its just not sorting with the highest points first to the lowest points last.

Comment: have you seen [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: @SatishSharma as mentioned I have looked but did not see this, ill take a look and see if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `usort`

You can do something like this:

```
usort($array, 'sortByPoints');

function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['points'] - $b['points'];
}
```

Yo can find more examples here: [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks Ill take a look into usort :)

Comment: Hi @Robert, just use `usort($array, 'sortByPoints');` do not use  `usort($multidimentional_array, array($this, 'sorting_table'));`

Answer (score 0):

Using `usort` Here is complete and tested code:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['points'] - $b['points'];
}

$test = array(
    0=> array(
        "name"=> "name",
        "gamesplayed" => "26",
        "points" => "26"
    ),
    1=> array(
        "name"=> "name",
        "gamesplayed" => "26",
        "points" => "42",
    ),
    2=> array(
        "name"=> "name",
        "gamesplayed" => "26",
        "points" => "16",
    )
);

usort($test, 'sortByOrder');
print_r($test);
```

Comment: I have updated my question to show what I have done, it does not work with the answer you gave, maybe I have implemented it incorrectly